# JavaMail : Limitations on the count for sending mails

Tags: email, smtp, jakarta-mail

Limitations on the count for sending emails using JavaMail

1. What is the maximum number of emails can be present in the to/cc/bcc
   list?
2. What is the maximum number of emails that can be sent in a
   Session?

Does these numbers depend on the SMTP server configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of those numbers depend on the server.  JavaMail imposes no limits other than available memory.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Any idea what are those limits for Gmail SMTP server?

Comment: No, and most likely Google doesn't publish them so that they can use an algorithm that attempts to detect spammers.

Comment: I think there is a limitation please check this.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?p=TooManyRecipientsError&visit_id=637708684177572931-2513818443&rd=1#zippy=%2Cyou-have-reached-a-limit-for-sending-mail