# James mail server : Limitations on the count for sending mails

Tags: java, email, james

My question is similar to this one here 
[JavaMail : Limitations on the count for sending mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358658/javamail-limitations-on-the-count-for-sending-mails)

We are using Apache James and I am trying to find out if there is any restriction/configuration on the number of users that I can add to a BCC list of a mail.

In old mailing list I found this one 
http://www.mail-archive.com/server-user@james.apache.org/msg02398.html.
It was an old answer and talks about configuration in future releases.

In current version of James, do they have options on limiting this?

Answer (score 0):

Looked through current RemoteDeliveryMailet code. It doesn't have any reference to configurations that will allow the limitation on number of mail destination.
This is not available yet , we have to do the limitation on our client side